# Cannot compile module in scilab

Tags: scilab

I made a scilab module and I have some troubles compiling it. Thought I tested on another computer and It works just fine.

When I execute:

```
exec builder.sce
```

Here is what I get:

```
-->mode(-1);
  error(msprintf(gettext('%s module not installed."),'development_tools'));
                                                          !--error 10000 
  development_tools module not installed.
  at line      30 of exec file called by :    
  exec builder.sce
```

I've search how to instal the development_tools but I cannot manage to find a solution.

Comment: Could you please specify your OS, SciLab version on both systems?

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but your quote marks don't match up around %s module not installed.

Comment: Well I have windows 8, scilab 5.4.1 on the first system (that does not work) and vista, scilab 5.4.0 on the other one (that compiles). I installed scilab 5.4.0 on the first computer and now it works. How can I make it work on scilab 5.4.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but since it is saying you're missing the system module **development_tools**. Your installation of 5.4.1 does not seem to be correct. Somebody had a problem with missing development_tools in Windows and asked it on the mailinglist [here](http://mailinglists.scilab.org/Problem-starting-scilab-5-0-3-td2610561.html#a2610585).

One of the answers mentioned that development_tools has to be explicitly selected. I don't know if this is still true but you could try reinstalling 5.4.1 and pay extra attention when the select components screen comes up.

[image: Select components]

You could also consult [this very extensive document](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~blanchet/FCFD/Scilab/docs/sciextensions-v0.2.pdf) about modules.

Could you try that and please post your results?